# server:run Exception There are no commands defined in the "server" namespace

Tags: php, symfony

When I run the server using `php bin/console server:run` I get the following error.
`There are no commands defined in the "server" namespace.`

When I run `php bin/console` command I egt the following output. Which does't show any server: commands.

```
Symfony 3.3.0-DEV (kernel: app, env: dev, debug: true)

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -e, --env=ENV         The environment name [default: "dev"]
      --no-debug        Switches off debug mode
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  about                                   Displays information about the current project
  help                                    Displays help for a command
  list                                    Lists commands
 app
  app:download-beameemail                 download beame emails.
  app:download-businessunits              download businessunits.
  app:download-drivers                    download drivers.
  app:download-fleets                     download fleets.
  app:download-fmpositions                download fm_positions.
  app:download-fmtrips                    download fm_trips.
  app:download-fmunits                    download fm_units.
  app:download-skypositions               download skytrack_positions.
  app:download-skyunits                   download skytrack_units.
  app:download-vehicles                   download vehicles.
 assets
  assets:install                          Installs bundles web assets under a public web directory
 cache
  cache:clear                             Clears the cache
  cache:pool:clear                        Clears cache pools
  cache:warmup                            Warms up an empty cache
 config
  config:dump-reference                   Dumps the default configuration for an extension
 debug
  debug:config                            Dumps the current configuration for an extension
  debug:container                         Displays current services for an application
  debug:event-dispatcher                  Displays configured listeners for an application
  debug:router                            Displays current routes for an application
  debug:swiftmailer                       [swiftmailer:debug] Displays current mailers for an application
  debug:translation                       Displays translation messages information
  debug:twig                              Shows a list of twig functions, filters, globals and tests
 doctrine
  doctrine:cache:clear-collection-region  Clear a second-level cache collection region.
  doctrine:cache:clear-entity-region      Clear a second-level cache entity region.
  doctrine:cache:clear-metadata           Clears all metadata cache for an entity manager
  doctrine:cache:clear-query              Clears all query cache for an entity manager
  doctrine:cache:clear-query-region       Clear a second-level cache query region.
  doctrine:cache:clear-result             Clears result cache for an entity manager
  doctrine:database:create                Creates the configured database
  doctrine:database:drop                  Drops the configured database
  doctrine:database:import                Import SQL file(s) directly to Database.
  doctrine:ensure-production-settings     Verify that Doctrine is properly configured for a production environment.
  doctrine:generate:crud                  [generate:doctrine:crud] Generates a CRUD based on a Doctrine entity
  doctrine:generate:entities              [generate:doctrine:entities] Generates entity classes and method stubs from your mapping information
  doctrine:generate:entity                [generate:doctrine:entity] Generates a new Doctrine entity inside a bundle
  doctrine:generate:form                  [generate:doctrine:form] Generates a form type class based on a Doctrine entity
  doctrine:mapping:convert                [orm:convert:mapping] Convert mapping information between supported formats.
  doctrine:mapping:import                 Imports mapping information from an existing database
  doctrine:mapping:info                   
  doctrine:query:dql                      Executes arbitrary DQL directly from the command line.
  doctrine:query:sql                      Executes arbitrary SQL directly from the command line.
  doctrine:schema:create                  Executes (or dumps) the SQL needed to generate the database schema
  doctrine:schema:drop                    Executes (or dumps) the SQL needed to drop the current database schema
  doctrine:schema:update                  Executes (or dumps) the SQL needed to update the database schema to match the current mapping metadata.
  doctrine:schema:validate                Validate the mapping files.
 fos
  fos:js-routing:debug                    Displays currently exposed routes for an application
  fos:js-routing:dump                     Dumps exposed routes to the filesystem
 generate
  generate:bundle                         Generates a bundle
  generate:command                        Generates a console command
  generate:controller                     Generates a controller
 lint
  lint:twig                               Lints a template and outputs encountered errors
  lint:xliff                              Lints a XLIFF file and outputs encountered errors
  lint:yaml                               Lints a file and outputs encountered errors
 router
  router:match                            Helps debug routes by simulating a path info match
 security
  security:check                          Checks security issues in your project dependencies
  security:encode-password                Encodes a password.
 swiftmailer
  swiftmailer:email:send                  Send simple email message
  swiftmailer:spool:send                  Sends emails from the spool
 translation
  translation:update                      Updates the translation file
```

I've tried to fix it by running `composer require symfony/symfony` and `composer update` but it still doesn't show.
Is there anything else that I can try?

Edit below is my php info from `php -version`

```
PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

EDIT 2

the directory `vendor\symfon\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command` exists and contains the following files

```
AboutCommand.php
AbstractConfigCommand.php
AssetsInstallCommand.php
CacheClearCommand.php
CachePoolClearCommand.php
CacheWarmupCommand.php
ConfigDebugCommand.php
ConfigDumpReferenceCommand.php
ContainerAwareCommand.php
ContainerDebugCommand.php
EventDispatcherDebugCommand.php
RouterDebugCommand.php
RouterMatchCommand.php
TranslationDebugCommand.php
TranslationUpdateCommand.php
WorkflowDumpCommand.php
XliffLintCommand.php
YamlLintCommand.php
```

Comment: Which php version are you using?

Comment: @MaulikSavaliya I've update my answer. using PHP 7.0.15

Comment: Can you please check `/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/`

Comment: @MaulikSavaliya the directory exists and contains several files but it doesn't seem to contain anything 'server' commands.

Comment: Why are you using the development version (3.3.0-DEV) of Symfony and how did you install it?  Looks like there has been a bit refactoring between 3.2 and 3.3.  A WebServerBundle has now been added along with some lines in AppKernel.php.  If you need to keep using the latest development version then I think you will need to install a fresh project and migrate your code.  One of the hazards I guess of being on the bleeding edge. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebServerBundle

Comment: thanks @Cerad I installed it using `composer require symfony/symfony` will try with version 3.2

Comment: @SarahRichardson - If you have a chance, try my answer below.  It may or may not work.

Comment: Please consider that u can simply change APP_ENV to "dev" to prevent this error

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, in S3.3 the server commands have been moved to their own WebServerBundle.  Some editing of AppKernel.php is required to activate the bundle.  I suspect that many other developers might run into this once 3.3 is actually released and people try upgrading.

I make no promises but try updating AppKernel.php with:

```
    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();

        if ('dev' === $this->getEnvironment()) {
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle();
        }
    }
```

I don't have a good test project to try it on but at least the commands should show up.

And in case anyone is wondering,  all I did was to install a fresh development project and poked around a bit.

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition s33 "3.3.*" --stability=dev
```

I also found this but it does not mention the need to update AppKernel.php 
http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-webserverbundle

From the upgrade guide: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/UPGRADE-3.3.md

> The server:run, server:start, server:stop and server:status console commands have been moved to a dedicated bundle. Require symfony/web-server-bundle in your composer.json and **register Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle** in your AppKernel to use them.

As long as your composer.json has symfony/symfony in it then there is no need to add the web server bundle to it.  Just need to adjust the AppKernel file.

Answer (score 33):

run this command before starting the server.

```
composer require symfony/web-server-bundle --dev
```

Comment: The right command is : composer require symfony/web-server-bundle --dev

Comment: This will install in dev environment so might not be visible in `bin/console`. If this happens run using `-e=dev` parameter (eg. `bin/console -e=dev server:run`) or add `APP_ENV=dev` in `.env` file.

Comment: You may need to specify a version: `composer require symfony/web-server-bundle --dev ^4.4.5`

Comment: For what it's worth, [the symfony/web-server-bundle is now deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74876716/9256002).

Answer (score 15):

you must execute this command:

```
composer req webserver
```

Comment: Helped me on Symfony 3.3 and PHP 7.1, was able to use server:run

Answer (score 8):

Type:

> php bin/console

You'll see all the commands allowed.

If you want to use the server commands you should install it typing on your project:

> composer require server --dev

run again

> php bin/console

and you should be able to see it and use it.

Answer (score 8):

As @Barh says, you must have `APP_ENV=dev` in your `.env` file.

Otherwise Symfony 4 **will not** be runnable in dev mode.

Comment: In symfony 4.2 and newer, the names of .env files have changed: [Nov 2018 Changes to .env & How to Update](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/dot-env-changes.html), [New in Symfony 4.2: Define env vars per environment](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-2-define-env-vars-per-environment)

Answer (score 4):

Verify that the correct APP_ENV is set in the environment.
In my case, it was critical.

Comment: Would be nice if you gave some examples here.

Answer (score 3):

you can put this:

```
  php -S localhost: 8000 -t public
```

or if you are working on symfony 4.x try this command line in your browser:

```
  symfony server: start
```

don't forget to install symfony CLI before this start from this:

```
  https://symfony.com/download
```

Comment: this worked for me but remove the blank spaces between text
php -S localhost:8000 -t public

Comment: also the space between `server:` and `start`

Answer (score 2):

Since symfony 4.2 and newer, theres is some changes so, to works you have to do this :

- 1: composer require symfony/web-server-bundle --dev
- 2: php bin\console **--env=dev** server:run

Answer (score 1):

upgrading from symfony <3.3 to symfony >3.3 will cause this problem because the web server was extracted out to a separate bundle.

so you'll need to require this bundle:

```
composer require symfony/web-server-bundle --dev
```

and in your AppKernel

```
 if ('dev' === $this->getEnvironment()) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle();
    }
```

for more info: [check here](https://codereviewvideos.com/course/upgrade-symfony-3-to-symfony-4/video/what-happened-to-the-webserver)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue on Symfony 4 after switching in `.env` to prod. Some commands are not visible on prod.

You either need to swap to dev or: 
`bin/console --env=dev`

And so to start server:
`bin/console --env=dev server:run 0.0.0.0:8005`

Answer (score 0):

For symfony 4 and more you should type `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public` to start the server

Answer (score 0):

1. Disabling firewall help
2. running......composer clear cache helped in allowing permission
3. running......composer req webserver helped clear my  commands defined in the "server" namespace

Answer (score 0):

Remove env.local file if you've it.

Reson:
Because server:run is not executing on production environment