# Symfony 3 (http://127.0.0.1:8000) doesn't work

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

I have the following errors:

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\gamenote\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle/Resources/router.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

I installed Symfony 3, and the first time when I ran the server with:

```
php bin/console server: run
```

with the URL **http://127.0.0.1:8000** it worked and displayed the homepage

**"Welcome to Symfony etc..."** but when I enter it a second time with the URL **http://127.0.0.1:8000**, it doesn't work anymore. Even when I stop and restart it doesn't work, and I haven't modified any files in the project. So I don't see why I saw the welcome page one time and after got that error because I didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you did not change anything at all because this sure sounds like the S3.1 -> S3.3 upgrade issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116427/serverrun-exception-there-are-no-commands-defined-in-the-server-namespace/43119148#43119148

Comment: Yeah I'm sure, I didn't upgrade and change something. And when I delete my project and create another one, it's the same it works one time and after display the same error... but in the console it still display : $ bin/console server:run

                                                                                
 [OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000                                 
                                                                                

 // Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just close the in the console?

Comment: You are using Windows and antivirus app is messing with symfony router.php file something i run into all the time when i am on windows, remove the vendor directory and then run `composer install` AFTER disabling your antivirus and all will run fine. I have to go through this problem several times in a week when i am on windows. Please stop using windows :)

Comment: I disabled my ativirus delete my project re install composer and create a new project with composer and now it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Delete `vendor` folder in your project
2. Execute inside your project (cmd) `composer install`
3. Run the server `php bin/console server:start`
4. Check in `localhost:8000`