# Runnning Symfony App Locally

Tags: php, symfony

I just started a new job, where the previous web developer created an app using the Symfony framework. I haven't used Symfony before but I'm familiar with Django and I noticed that they have a very similar structure. The codebase was hosted in a gitlab repo and I was able to download a zip file onto my local computer. 
I started reading the documentation on how to setup and install a Symfony application but I noticed that there are many differences between what I downloaded and what a 'standard' Symfony app should look like. My ultimate goal is to run this app on `localhost` to test out some improvements.

I started debugging every problem I faced and have defeated some bugs but they just keep coming. I'll post some files that I think are relevant to my problem as well as the structure of my directory.

Edit: New Composer.json file after cleaning up.

`composer.json`:

```
   {
  "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" },
    "files": [ "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php" ]
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "platform": {
      "php": "5.5.9"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
      "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "3.4-dev"
    }
  }
}
```

I had to add `"files":["app/AppKernel.php"],` to the composer to stop an error was was complaining about not finding the Kernel.

`AppKernel.php`:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
 {
  public function registerBundles()
  {
      $bundles = [
          new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
          new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
          new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
          new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
          new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
          new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new 
 Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
                new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
      ];

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new 
Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();

        if ('dev' === $this->getEnvironment()) {
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle();
        }
    }

    return $bundles;
}

public function getRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__;
}

public function getCacheDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
}

public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load(function (ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $container->setParameter('container.autowiring.strict_mode', true);
        $container->setParameter('container.dumper.inline_class_loader', true);

        $container->addObjectResource($this);
    });
    $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
}
```

The main problem I'm running into now is `Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel' not found in /Users/.../app/AppKernel.php on line 7` after running `php bin/console server:start`. This app kernel file wasn't even in the repo and I had to copy it from a standard symfony app, which also solved some errors.

`bin/console`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php


require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
//use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// if you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup
// for more information
//umask(0000);

set_time_limit(0);

$input = new ArgvInput();
$env = $input->getParameterOption(['--env', '-e'], getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'dev');
$debug = getenv('SYMFONY_DEBUG') !== '0' && !$input->hasParameterOption(['--no-debug', '']) && $env !== 'prod';

if ($debug) {
    Debug::enable();
}

$kernel = new AppKernel($env, $debug);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->run($input);
```

This file wasn't there as well and I had to copy it too, I also have `use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;` commented out because it threw an error saying that this class didn't exist.

I know this question is pretty open ended but essentially, I just wanted to know how to be able to run this app locally, I have read many github issue threads, SO questions and the documentation but to no avail.

Please let me know if you want any additional information/files, I'm trying to run on this on Mac OSX.

Edit: Was able to finally create a clean project but now running into a peculiar issue.

Running `php bin/console server:start` provides this error: `There are no commands defined in the "server" namespace.` I looked at this ([server:run Exception There are no commands defined in the "server" namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116427/serverrun-exception-there-are-no-commands-defined-in-the-server-namespace)[question]) but my `AppKernel.php` seems to match the one provided in the accepted answer.

Edit2: Output of `bin/console list` is :

```
Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  help  Displays help for a command
  list  Lists commands
```

Comment: You should try using the symfony installer in order to get the standard edition, that way it setups the entire thing and avoid as many bugs as possible, i will recommend version 2.8 and ^3 and also read on symfony flex

Comment: @Ezekiel That will create a fresh app if I'm not mistaken? And I need to use the existing project but they don't match up and I tried copying relevant folders into a fresh app but also ran into many errors since I have a feeling there are config files that have been changed for that specific project

Comment: definitely there will be configs changed, all you have to do is copy the previous appkernel file and replace it with the new one, you can just add any code not there, then copy the previous one composer.jsom and run composer install, then also all the necessary models,controllers and views necessary

Comment: Also the config files, such as where there are firewall and database settings

Comment: Download the project, run `composer update` and run it.

Comment: Based on your composer.json file your app is not based in the Symfony framework but rather uses some Symfony components.  Looks like it is some kind of home grown framework.  Is it to late to change jobs?

Comment: Do not run `composer update`! This will update the dependencies and might lead to new errors you have to deal with. Use `composer install` instead. This will use the previously set dependencies from your `composer.lock` which you should always commit.

Comment: @Cerad I got that feeling looking through the project and after more inspection, it seems like this is using another framework called [Magister](https://github.com/MagnaXSoftware/Magister)

Answer (score 1):

With a somewhat standard Symfony application what you minimally need is:

- PHP on your local machine
- likely a database like MySQL (sometimes sqlite works as an easy local replacement)

You can clone the repository or download the source as zip as you did. Using a terminal go to your project folder and do the following:

```
composer install
```

This should download all required dependencies described in your composer.json. At the very end it might ask you for some parameters like database settings. If not, check `app/configs/parameters.yml.dist` and copy the file without the `.dist` extension. Then update the parameters using your preferred text editor.

Now you should be ready to set up your development database:

```
bin/console doctrine:database:create
bin/console doctrine:schema:create
```

This should create an empty database schema. Your project might also have fixtures and migrations. Just check for the commands using `bin/console list` if necessary. You might also have an (anonymized) database dump from your production database you could reuse.

Now all you need is to run a webserver. For development Symfony has a command as well:

```
bin/console server:start
```

This will start the server in the background and keep it running. Now you should be able to open the site in your browser using http://localhost:8000

Comment: I ran `composer install` and added the parameters it asked me for but I haven't looked at databases yet. Will try to run the commands now, thanks for your help!

Comment: `bin/console doctrine:database:create` this gives me the same error `Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel' not found`

Comment: Kernel class should be installed by composer. Do you have a vendor folder and can you search for the file in there?

Comment: @dburmann Yes I have a vendor folder, after a quick pass, I can't locate the file.

Comment: Okay I managed to add the HttpKernel class to composer json and install it, now I'm getting another error `'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application' not found`

Comment: Weird question, but you said you had to create `bin/console` did `app/console` exist by chance? I think this might be related to using an older Symfony version. You should have the command in the original console app though, according to docs: https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/web_server/built_in.html

Comment: Nope, app/console didn't exist. After my fresh installation however, I am now running Symfony 3.4.*. `bin/console doctrine:database:create` is also giving me the same issue saying `There are no commands defined in the "doctrine:database" namespace`

Comment: Additionally, running `php bin/console` to see all the commands gives this error : `Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppKernel could not be converted to string` in `TextDescriptor.php`

Comment: If you updated to 3.4 you should check the old upgrade notes to make sure your application, which - judging by the composer.json - is 2.6-based works properly. e.g. https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.8.md
No commands being defined might be related to autowiring for the commands, but sounds a bit weird. Can you print the output of `bin/console list`?

Comment: Didn't see the second message. In that case I would try forcing an older version of Symfony first to match what composer.json expects. Try 2.6 or 2.8. I think some of your issues are the result of missed upgrades to the project. For example try using the older AppKernel without the autowiring changes you have in there: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.8/app/AppKernel.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163562/discussion-between-ybce-and-dbrumann).