# Error : Composer require symfony/web-server-bundle

Tags: php, docker, symfony, nginx

I tried to execute a symfony project within a docker container by "php bin/console server:run " but it generate the following error :

> "There are no commands defined in the "server" namespace.
> You may be looking for a command provided by the "Debug Bundle" which
> is currently not installed. Try running "composer require
> symfony/debug-bundle --dev". ]"

Then i tried to install this package, but the error persist .

And i tried to install  `symfony/web-server-bundle package` too, but another error display:

> "Composer require symfony/web-server-bundle Info from
> https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine ./composer.json has been
> updated Running composer update symfony/web-server-bundle Loading
> composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.   Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires symfony/web-server-bundle 6.1.*, found symfony/web-server-bundle[v3.3.0-BETA1, ..., 3.4.x-dev,
> v4.0.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint.
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to
> their original content "

Answer (score 1):

The symfony/web-server-bundle is now deprecated.

For a dev environment, you can try installing the Symfony cli https://symfony.com/download. I don't know what docker image you are using, but the doc has instructions for installation on multiple different linux environments.

Then you can use the **Symfony local server**: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html.

Typically the command to run the server is:

```
symfony server:start
```

*A side note: when using docker you will also need to expose the port the web server runs the application on if you want to access it.*